# I have a iframe which is not getting enabled for design from a seperate.js file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

The code for the iframe declaration in my sample.asp file is as follows

```
`<iframe width="100%" id="idContent" height="100%" ></iframe>`
```

the code utilized in dummy.js file to enable the iframe is

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('idContent').addEventListener("mouseover", handler1);
});
function handler1() {
    var iframe1= document.getelementbyid('idcontent');
    ifram1.document.contentDocument.designMode="on";
    alert("enabled");
};
```

the above code does not enable any design of the page.

the below code enables the entire page where as i require only one iframe( idcontent) to be enabled.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('idContent').addEventListener("mouseover", handler1);
});
function handler1() {
    document.designMode="on";
    alert("enabled");
};
```

can you please suggesst how can i enable the design mode of the iframe. help is appreciated.

Comment: why `ifram1.document.contentDocument.designMode="on";` and not just `ifram1.designMode="on";`? Also what is the purpose of designMode? What is your goal with enabling designMode?

Comment: The iframe is a rick text editor in which i would require to have some manipulation and formatting in the text typed in the editor.

Comment: The problem is i have a application in which some functionality is not supported by chrome. upon investigating i found it to be chrome does not support the inline event handler. hence i had to move the script to a seprate js file and fix the issue . but in IE the iframe was activated as idcontent.document.design="on"; which did not work in chrome.

Comment: Changing the value did not enable the iframe as suggested ifram1.designMode="on";?

Comment: is the content of your iframe local - this :- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/e3eRJy3vXSM and this: - http://www.projectinsight.net/support/kb/chrome-blocks-iframe